# How can I prevent my React application from including Bootstrap in the bundle?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm new at React.JS and I have made some sample app to test it, in my site I've already have the call to bootstrap CDN so I don't need to call bootstrap again in my React APP, but when I run 'npm run build', in the output, bootstrap code is appended to the css file, how can I disable bootstrap in my project.

Thank you...

UPDATE:

This is my package.json file, I've already remove the call from this file, but it still appending bootstrap.

```
{
  "name": "new-home",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage" : "home/newHome/build",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to show us your app build configuration, but my guess is that Bootstrap is listed in your package.json file.

Comment: Please add your complete package.json file. Maybe you are not directly importing the library but another library might be using it. Also, css files could import another css file directly using  [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

In index.js I needed to remove the import call to bootstrap, in my case I removed but I recommend just comment it.

Thanks everyone...

Answer (score -1):

If you have not Ejected(which isnt recommended for newer react users) than you may not be able to see it in your package.json file, but on eject you will see it in there.